# Sails.js filtering records using the route

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am very new to Sails.js and I am trying to understand its magic.

I have three nested models using associations : Series.js -> Season.js -> and Episode.js.

```
Series.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    /* other attributes */

    seasons: {
      collection: 'season',
      via: 'series'
    }

  } 
};

Season.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    /* other attributes */

    episodes: {
      collection: 'episode',
      via: 'season'
    },
    series: {
      model: 'series'
    }

  } 
};

Episode.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    /* other attributes */

    season: {
      model: 'season'
    }

  } 
};
```

Out of the box, I can get the seasons of a series using the route:

> /series/:id/seasons

And also the episodes of a season using the route:

> /seasons/:id/episodes

What I don't understand is why I can't get the episodes of a season of a series using this route:

> series/:id/seasons/:id/episodes

Any idea why is this happening? I know I could use custom routes to get the behaviour I want, but it'd be nice to be able to do it without any further configuration.

I know Sails.js only allows one level population, but this doesn't seem the issue since I have set `populate: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails doesn't provide this route automatically:

```
series/:id/seasons/:id/episodes
```

because it doesn't really make sense if you think about it.  If you already know the ID of the season, then the series it belongs to is irrelevant.  Just use:

```
seasons/:id/episodes
```

to get the episodes you want.